# sharepoint search 2010 xml file

Tags: search

i was looking for source to connect our sharepoint 2010 search to external folder having xml files inside it.We crawled the folder but we are getting the results with xml file names.But we nwant to see the results associated with one of the internal property of xml files.is it possible to query the internal property of xml files in the folder to show the search results, Please suggest some ways .thanks in advance...